# Perl Regex for Substituting Any Character

Tags: regex, perl, character, substitution, any

Essentially, I want to replace the u between the random character and the k to be an o. The output I should get from the substitution is dudok and rujok.

How can I do this in Perl? I'm very new to Perl so go easy on me.

This is what I have right now:

```
$text = "duduk, rujuk";
$_ = $text;
s/.uk/ok/g
print $_; #Output: duok, ruok Expected: dudok, rujok
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the last syllable is the only one that should be changed. Also, the random character is specifically supposed to be a random consonant, not just any random character.

I should mention that this is all based on Malay language rules for grapheme to phoneme conversion.

Comment: what should dukuk become?

Comment: dukuk would become dukok as the last syllable should be changed only. Though dukuk is not an actual Malay word! Haha

Comment: so rukuk -> rukok but alukan would remain unchanged?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malay_alphabet), the Malayan language uses an unaccented latin alphabet, and it has the same consonants as the English language. However, its digraphs are different than English's.

- ai vowel
- au vowel
- oi vowel
- gh consonant
- kh consonant
- ng consonant
- ny consonant
- sy consonant

So, if one wanted to find a syllable ending with `uk`, one would look for

```
<syllable_boundary>(?:[bcdfhjlmpqrtvwxyz]|gh?|kh?|n[gv]?|sv?)uk
```

or

```
<syllable_boundary>uk
```

The OP is specifically disinterested in the latter, so we simply need to look for

```
<syllable_boundary>(?:[bcdfhjlmpqrtvwxyz]|gh?|kh?|n[gv]?|sv?)uk
```

So now, we have to determine how to find a syllable boundary. ...or do we? All the consonant digraphs end with a consonant, and none of the vowel digraphs end in a consonant so we simply need to look for

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]uk
```

Finally, we can use `\b` to check for the end of the word, so we're interested in matching

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]uk\b
```

---

Now, let's use this in a substitution.

```
s/([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])uk\b/$1ok/g
```

or

```
s/(?<=[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])uk\b/ok/g
```

or

```
s/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]\Kuk\b/ok/g
```

The last one is the most efficient, but it requires Perl 5.10+. (That shouldn't be a problem given how ancient it is.)

Comment: Updated to account for the major change to the question. (@ysth)

Comment: Or quite simply we could use [^aeiou] where it's essentially "not vowel" which is equivalent to "consonant". Correct?

Comment: That match way too much. And even if it was equivalent, I doubt it would be faster

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to:

```
s/(.)uk/$1ok/g;
```

Comment: Cool, works marvelously. Thank you so much! Can you explain a bit on what it's doing? Is it storing the character to a question mark and then we access that question mark with $1? Please help me on the proper terms. Haha

Comment: Fixed the obvious mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

As ikegami raised, the word "bukuk" would have two substitutions. This is not the desired outcome as only the last syllable should be changed. Also, I forgot to mention that the change should only be done for a random consonant, u, and followed by k (e.g. ruk, not auk).

As such, taking everything into account that has been answered, the correct regex should be:

```
s/(\w*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])uk\b/$1ok/g;
```

EDIT: As ikegami has raised again, the complement of vowels - [^aeiou] will match for other characters like "-" and " " which is undesired. Updated the solution.

Comment: This is based on Malay language rules. Sorry I didn't specify about the last syllable rule in the question. I'll edit it in now.

Comment: Re "*Sorry I didn't specify about the last syllable rule in the question.*", That's not what I was saying; I was saying you didn't check of the match was in the last syllable. But that's wrong. I had overlooked the `\b`. Sorry, downvote and comment removed. (As well as the request to fix the question, which is now moot)

Comment: Ah right, because I'm using complement of the vowels. Will update the regex then.

Comment: All right now that I understand the nuances a bit better, I've decided to just accept your answer to the question. Thank you so much for your input!